# Passing a timestamp through a PHP form, and formatting it on second page

Tags: php, forms, date, time, timestamp

This is a very basic project for a PHP class I am in - no databases involved so the data isn't going anywhere except the next page.

Currently, I am formatting the date on the page with the form using a hidden field, and it gets passed through in the URL post-formatting (with all the spaces punctuation).  That satisfies the requirements of the assignment, but does not seem like the cleanest way to do this.

The form is "Comp2.php" and the page that displays the data is "Comp2b.php"

Here are the code segments in question:
(There are other fields in play of course, but I left them out since they are just text)

Comp2.php

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $valid = true;
        $dateadded = $_POST['dateadded'];

        if ($valid) {
            header("Location: Comp2b.php?albumid=$albumid&album=$album&artist=$artist&dateadded=$dateadded");
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        $albumid="";
        $artist="";
        $album="";
        $price="";
        $type="";
        $playlists[0]="";
        $genre="";
        $tracks="";

    }
?>
    <form method="post" action="Comp2.php">

<?php $currentDate = date('l, F d, Y h:i:s a.') ?>

            <input type="hidden" name="dateadded" value="<?php echo $currentDate; ?>">
```

Then the rest of the form continues...

This is
Comp2b.php:

```
<?php

    echo "Album ID: <strong>";
    echo $_GET['albumid']."</strong><p><strong>".$_GET['album']."</strong> by <strong>".$_GET['artist']."</strong> added on ".$_GET['dateadded'];

?>
```

How can I pass something like `date()` or `time()` through the form, and do the formatting i.e., `date('l, F d, Y h:i:s a.', $dateadded)` on my second page instead of passing a full string through the URL?

Comment: You are using get and your form is on post, use `$_POST[]` instead

Comment: Well as its a date there is no need to pass it from first to second form. Its a date, it will be the same in the first form and the second form. So do anything and everything with the data in the second form where you will actually show it to a user

Comment: @multimediaxp Are you saying all my `$_GET[]`s should be `$_POST[]`s on the second page?

Comment: just pass it as a unix timestamp, then in the second page, then use `date()`, just pass `time()` in the query string

Comment: @RiggsFolly  My issue with that is, what if I leave that second page open for a day and then hit refresh? It would display the current time at the time of the refresh, correct?  I'd like it to display the original time the user hit SUBMIT on the form.

Comment: Ok, good point, those day long web views can be a bitch. In that case take @Ghost suggestion. Pass a simple unix timestamp and just format it in the second form to look any way you like it to. Oh and YES, Second pages `$_GET` should be `$_POST`

Comment: @Ghost - I tried to do that, using the unix time then formatting it, but it gives me errors if I put the formatting inside the `$_GET[]` like `$_GET[date('l, F d, Y h:i:s a.', $dateadded)]`

Comment: @user6169443 append it in the query string, then get the get variable just like you're used to, then apply that `date()` function, just like Riggs' answer below

Answer (score 1):

In the first page put a simple `time()` in the hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="dateadded" value="<?php echo time(); ?>">
```

Then in the second page output that timestamp formatted any way you like

```
<?php

    echo "Album ID: <strong>";
    echo $_POST['albumid'];
    echo '</strong><p><strong>'.$_POST['album'];
    echo '</strong> by <strong>' . $_POST['artist'];
    echo ' </strong> added on ' . date('l, F d, Y h:i:s a.', $_POST['dateadded']);

?>
```

> Reasons:
>
> time() generates a simple number like 876243672834 which is much easier to pass around and less likely to cause confusion.
>
> 'date()` can have 2 parameter, the first is a format, and the second is a timestamp representing a date and time in unix format.
>
> Also because your form `<form method="post"` has a method of `post` the data will end up in the `$_POST` array and not the `$_GET` array
>
> The `$_GET` array is populated when you do things like `<a href="xxx.php?a=1&b=2">` or use `<form method="GET"`

Comment: Sorry @Ghost I pressed save 1 milli second after you. I rolled back and then applied my additional stuff to your edit

Comment: Ahhhh. Thanks.  Didn't know I had to (or could) format the whole `$_POST[]`.   Makes sense though.

Comment: Occurances in the `$_POST` or `$_GET` array are just data. Once PHP delivers you this array its all yours, just like an array you built for yourself. There is absolutely no reason to move occurances out to a scalar variable, it just wastes memory and time

Comment: Oh and by the way, when you use `<form method="POST"` the data is not passed on the URL as a querystring

Comment: So this is curious, I swapped GET for POST on the second page, and I get no data except for the date, which is "Wednesday, December 31, 1969 06:00:00 pm.," but I do see the data from all the fields up in the URL.

Comment: What does your SUBMIT button look like?

Comment: `<form method="POST" action="Comp2.php">` and the actual button is `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Album">`

Comment: You will have to make `<input...` fields for all the data values either hidden or user enterable. POST only sends values from `<input...` fields. And of course remove the `header()` stuff completely

Comment: Thanks for asking that.  I noticed my action was pointing to the wrong file. Should have been Comp2b.php.  All works fine now using $_POST.

Another question I have now is, I have this bit of code hanging out:

        if ($valid) { header("Location: Comp2b.php?albumid=$albumid&        album=$album&artist=$artist&dateadded=$dateadded");`  

Do I still need it?

EDIT: Heh, just saw your post. Awesome.

Comment: I'm pretty surprised my instructor didn't say something about me using that wierd POST/GET hybrid.

Comment: I didn't spot it straight off so maybe (s)he didn't either